# How to delete openssl dlls before closing the application

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy

I made a simple tool (LogAndMailApplication) that sends logs to my gmail account, for this I used the Indy component TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL. To work it needs ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll.

So at application start I extract from exe resources the 2 dll and I copy them to the application folder.

All the indy compoennts are in a datamodule I destroy before closing the application.

After destroying the datamodule I try to delete the dlls but I cannot.

I just used DeleteFile, but that worked great for all the other files I delete on application exit (incluging an ini file).

I tried to make a simple exe that just deletes the 2 dll and it works. So the problem is that the 2 dll are somehow locked until the LogAndMailApplication is not closed, how to solve the problem?

Comment: if the DLLs are hidden in the executable, how can users or administrators replace the DLLS by a newer version, if they need a critical security patch?

Comment: They cannot, but it is not something that makes sense here. I am just sending an e-mail to myself. I install this on 3 customers only, so for now it is managable.

Comment: Why do you need to delete the DLLs at all? Why not just keep them there in the application directory so they're ready to use next time? (And for that matter, why don't you just make the *installer* put them there?)

Comment: If your application extracts the dll's to the application folder, it will require to run with elevated privileges on vista or newer windows with UAC enabled (the default).  As Rob suggest, the installer should put them there.

Comment: Ok. this is just a quick and dirty tool, i don't need an installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following: at the very end of your code use

FreeLibrary(GetModuleHandle('ssleay32.dll'));
FreeLibrary(GetModuleHandle('libeay32.dll'));
DeleteFile(PathToDLL1);
DeleteFile(PathToDLL2);

This should work.

Alternatively you can get rid of OpenSSL and use [SSL components](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/delphi-ssl.php) from our SecureBlackbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion worked (and now I now how to unregister dlls).

Comment: This is bad advise. Indy has a lot of references to the DLL functions, allocated objects (callbacks, etc) passed in/out of the DLLs, etc. Unloading the DLLs directly using FreeLibrary() alone does not allow Indy to clean up anything it is using internally. Indy has its own functions for unloading the DLLs safely. You should be using those instead.  See my other answer.

Comment: @Remy in fact, unloading the DLLs at shutdown should not cause any problems unless you keep pointers to library objects that you access on shutdown. Though, of course, calling your method is a better solution. And getting rid of OpenSSL is way better.

Comment: If you call FreeLibrary() directly, Indy has no way of knowing that, and will try to unload the DLLs again.  That may cause erros, crashes, etc.  Since Indy is the one who loaded the DLLs, Indy should be the one to unload them.

Comment: @Remy and how is calling FreeLibrary on the invalid handle prone to errors crashes etc.? Windows will handle it gently.

Comment: Indy calls several OpenSSL DLL functions during its unloading logic, so if the DLLs are unloaded manually, those functions cannot be called correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Indy dynamically loads the OpenSSL DLLs at runtime, and then by default does not unload them until app shutdown.  If you want to unload the DLLs sooner, you need to call `IdSSLOpenSSL.UnLoadOpenSSLLibrary()` directly.  This will unload the DLLs and clean up all references and allocated objects related to them.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can delete the DLL's in the finalization section of the data module unit...